# Discover hWnd where mouse is

Tags: winapi, hwnd

A long time ago I remember using a program where I just moved my mouse around the screen and it displayed the hWnd information (and some other stuff) of the window (and parent, and child) to where you were pointing your mouse.  Does anyone know of something like this? I cant find it anymore.

(btw this is  windows 7)

*Edited*: it's not yet any of these, but Winspector seems to do what I want.  I remember that it was done by a guy that was a master in window Subclassing in the VB5/6 days

Comment: Is this for just the application or is it for all applications? I assume all applications but it would be easy to do for just your application if that is what you need.

Comment: Also, there is a mouse capture feature. If you don't need to use the mouse for another application when you move the mouse around then mouse capture would allow reporting the mouse position.

Answer (score 2):

[Windowse](http://www.greatis.com/delphicb/windowse/) is free, lightweight and great. I use it anytime I don't have an explicit need for the extra functionality the much heavier Spy++ offers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of the [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264396(VS.60).aspx) utility that comes with Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

What about using GetCursorPos and then use RealChildWindowFromPoint, [WindowFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633558%28VS.85%29.aspx) or ChildWindowFromPoint? You maybe want to define a global hook to be informed about all mouse movements.

**Update**

Btw. if you are sill looking for such a program, I suggest [Winspector](http://www.windows-spy.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Could you be thinking of [WinCheat](http://alinconstantin.dtdns.net/Download/WinCheat/_Default.htm)? I use it all the time at work, it's very useful. It does have some of the same features as Spy++, but it makes it easier to get more information about a window, IMO.