# What is the (technical) difference between a Label and a TextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have seen a lot of answers on the web stating that a Label's text can't be selected/copied in the way that a `TextBox`'s contents can,
but what is the *underlying reason* that a `Label`'s text can't be copied?

Windows itself can find text under the cursor position, so why can't the WinForm `Label` control?

Comment: I don't have a specific reference, but I would expect this is a design issue, not a technical one.

Comment: What do you mean by _Windows itself can find text under the cursor position_?

Comment: I'm sure I recall an API call (seen years ago when I did VB6) which returns the text (i.e.word) which the cursor is over.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order for a user to select or copy a control's text, the control must allow you to set focus to it, either by clicking or <kbd>tab</kbd>ing to the control.

A [Label](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't allow this, by design.

> Label controls are typically used to provide descriptive text for a control. For example, you can use a Label to add descriptive text for a TextBox control to inform the user about the type of data expected in the control.

So while Labels and TextBoxes both inherit from [System.Windows.Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx) they are different things, intended for different purposes. In the same way that oranges and apples are both fruit, but are different.

**However**, if you're creating an application and want to have something that *looks like* a label, but allows the user to select (but not edit) the text, then you can use a [TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx) with the following properties set:

- `Backcolor = Control`
- `ReadOnly = true`
- `BorderStyle = none`

As shown below...

[image: A textbox that looks like a label]

**Alternatively**, if you have an application and want to get text from something like a label, you can use the Win32 API function [`GetWindowText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx), if you know the handle to the window that contains the text. In a Win32 context a "window" means just about anything distinct that is on the screen, not just the windows that you can drag around with your mouse. [WinForms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) is an abstraction on top of all this.

As for getting the handle to the window that is under the mouse cursor, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111618/discover-hwnd-where-mouse-is).

Comment: .....I had no idea that labels weren't selectable.... #MindBlown.... Btw, did you really fend off an elephant with a laptop? Brah, that's not how you use laptops....

Comment: @AnthonyRussell - you know, I actually did! On holiday in Zambia, Africa a few years ago, we'd been warned there were some male adolescents in heat near where we were staying. One approached us from behind some trees one evening. I shouted at it and waved my laptop around, which did the trick and it backed off. Those things are biiiiiiig!

Comment: What brand of laptop?

Comment: Company-supplied Dell. ;)
I had it with me so that I could copy photos over from my camera.

Comment: Probably a Mac fan. They always use nature names in their OS

Comment: You could also notice that a label have an Image property, the textbox doesn't.

Label also support Mnemonic (ALT + ... To focus a control) but could not have focus, it will be moved to the next control in the TabOrder (which could be a Textbox by exemple).

Comment: Thanks Richard for the explanation.
The GetWindowText API call is probably the one I recall from VB6 days,
coupled with obtaining the Handle of the Window the mouse is in....